# Dynamically creating nested functions from a yaml script

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, nested

I have a yaml script that we use to specify functions. The yaml file parses into a dictionary (actually, nested dictionaries) that I want to use to construct the functions described in this yaml file. Here's an example yaml entry:

```
Resistance:
   arguments:
      voltage: "V"
      current: "A"
   parameters:
      a: -1.23
      b: 0.772
   format: "{a}*voltage+{b}*current+f(voltage)"
   subfunctions:
      f:
         arguments:
            voltage: "V"             
         parameters:
            a: -6.32          
         format: "exp({a}*voltage)"
```

Now, what need to do is parse this file and then build up the namespaces so that at the end, I can bind a variable called "Resistance" to a closure or lambda that reflects the above function (with nested "f" subfunction).

My strategy was to go "bottom up" using a recursive algorithm. Here is my code:

```
def evaluateSimpleFunction(entry):
    functionString = entry['format']    
    functionArgs = []
    Params = []

    if "arguments" in entry and entry["arguments"] != None:
        functionArgs = entry['arguments'].keys()
    if "parameters" in entry and entry["parameters"] != None:
        Params = entry['parameters']

    formatString = ""
    for param in Params:
        formatString += str(param)+"="+str(Params[param])+","
    functionString = eval("functionString.format("+formatString+")")

    lambdaString = ""
    for arg in functionArgs:
        lambdaString += str(arg)+","

    return eval("lambda " + lambdaString + ":" + functionString)

def recursiveLoader(entry):
    if "subfunctions" in entry:
        subfunctions = entry['subfunctions']
        bindingString = ""
        for subFunc in subfunctions:
            bindingString +=str(subFunc)+"=[];"
            exec(bindingString)
        for subFunc in subfunctions:
            exec(str(subFunc)+"= recursiveLoader(subfunctions[subFunc])")      
        return lambda : evaluateSimpleFunction(entry)            
    else:
        return lambda : evaluateSimpleFunction(entry)


import yaml,os, math
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\212544808\Desktop\PySim\xferdb")
keyFields = ["Resistance","OCV"]
containerKeys = ["_internalResistance","_OCV"]
functionContainer = {}

with open("LGJP1.yml",'r') as modelFile:
    parsedModelFile = yaml.load(modelFile)

#for funcKey,containerKey in zip(keyFields,containerKeys):  
entry = parsedModelFile["capacityDegrade"]
g = recursiveLoader(entry)
```

Now, as it stands, I get an error because I am using unqualified exec with a nested function.

However, I don't want to resort to globals, because I will use this process for multiple functions and will therefore overwrite any globals I use.

I'm hoping for suggestions on how to construct nested functions algorithmically from an external config file like the yaml file - exec doesn't seem to be the way to go.

BTW: I'm using Python 2.7

**UPPDATE**

Another, more robust option may be to use a global class instance to create a namespace for each function. For example:

```
class Namespace(): pass

namespace_1 = Namespace()
#assume that the function "exponent" has arguments X, Y and body "Q(X*Y)", 
#where "Q" has body "x**2+3*y"
exec("namespace_1.exponent = lambda X,Y: Q(X*Y)")
exec("namespace_1.Q = lambda x,y: x**2+3*y")
```

The benefit of this approach is that I can then loop through the members of the class for a particular function to create a single source code string that I can pass to "eval" to get the final function.

I'm doing all of this because I have not found a reliable way to create nested closures using eval and exec.

Comment: Why not compile the yaml into a python module and import it?

Comment: @KurtStutsman Is that different than yaml.load()? I already have the yaml file imported as a Python dict.

Comment: Yes. You process your file and write out a python module as a .py file. Then you can use `import()` function to load it.

Comment: @KurtStutsman interesting. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified example of what I mean using your input. I have hardcoded it, but you could easily build up a similar module file using your parser:

```
def makeModule(**kwargs):
    print repr(kwargs)

    module_filename = 'generated_module.py'
    with open(module_filename, 'w') as module_file:
        module_file.write('''\
from math import *

def func(voltage, current):
    def f(voltage):
        return exp({a1} * voltage)

    return {a0}*voltage+{b}*current+f(voltage)
'''.format(**kwargs))

    module_name = module_filename.replace('.py', '')
    module = __import__(module_name)
    return module.func

def main():
    func = makeModule(a0=-1.23, b=0.772, a1=-6.32)
    print 'Result:', func(2, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works by generating a file called *generated_module.py* and then using the builtin function `__import__` to import it as a module that is stored into the variable `module`. Like any other module, then you can access the names defined in it, namely `func`.

Comment: Thx! That was helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to "generate" the function without having a file; i.e. load the function into the interpreter? I am working on a project, that uses JSON files to describe callable objects. JSON-files do have "python" logic embedded into them.